# PHP/MySQL dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a main MySQL table called `restaurants` which holds all details for each restaurant - `RestaurantID`, `RestaurantName`, `Address`, `Town`, `County` etc.

I am creating a Review and ratings form in PHP to allow my users to review each of the restaurants.  I have created 2 dropdown menus one which the user will select the County and the second I hope to populate with RestaurantName of those in that County.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?  My first dropdown populates without any issues, although the second dropdown is blank?

I've added all my code so far for this, anything else that you think would be useful let me know.

**leave.php**

```
<?php
include_once "settings.php"
?>

<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div class="County">
        <label>County</label>
        <select name = "County" onchange="getId(this.value);">
            <option value ="">Select County </option>


            <?php
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT County FROM restaurants";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

foreach ($results as $restaurants) {
    ?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $restaurants['County']; ?>"><?php echo $restaurants["County"]; ?></option>

        <?php
    }
    ?>

        </select>
    </div>

        <div class="RestName">
        <label>Restaurant</label>
        <select name = "Restaurant" id="RestList">
            <option value ="">Select Restaurant </option>

                 <option value="" >
            <?php

include_once "settings.php";

if (!empty($_POST["RestaurantID"])) {
    $RestaurantID = $_POST["RestaurantID"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE RestaurantID = $RestaurantID";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

foreach ($results as $County) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo $restaurants["RestaurantID"]; ?>"><?php echo $restaurants["RestaurantName"]; ?>"></option>

<?php
}


}

?> 
        </select>
    </div>

    <script>
    function getId(val){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"getdata.php",
            data: "RestaurantID="+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#RestList").html(data);

            }
        });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**getdata.php**

```
<?php

include_once "settings.php";

if (!empty($_POST["RestaurantID"])) {
    $RestaurantID = $_POST["RestaurantID"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE RestaurantID = $RestaurantID";
    $results = 
    ($con, $query);

foreach ($results as $restaurants) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo $restaurants['RestaurantID']; ?>"><?php echo $restaurants["RestaurantName"]; ?>"></option>

<?php
}

}
?>
```

Comment: `<select name="Restaurant" id="RestList" </select>` and `<option value="" </option>` are both invalid HTML. `$results=m ysqli_query($con, $query);` is also broken (space breaks the function). And you're not looping through the results, because it's commented out.

Comment: Ok, so I've fixed everything mentioned and still no joy?

Comment: Share the current code - update your post with it. As for the `//populate value using PHP` comments, that won't happen unless you instruct PHP do actually do something.

Comment: Ok I've re-edited it with my updated code, I've never used StackOverflow before hence having no idea how to insert my code in a nicer way. Sorrry.

Comment: Alright. You should probably format your code a bit better (with proper indenting, running your code through a codeformatter does that for you), might help troubleshoot. Now, you said your second dropdown doesn't populate. I'm assuming you mean `Restaurant` one. For one, `foreach ($results as $County) {` and then using `$restaurants['RestaurantID']` won't work. `$County` != `$restaurants`. Be careful with the names of your variables. Also, you just *assume* that your queries work - look into error-handling and error-reporting.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<select name="Restaurant" id="RestList" </select>
```

You don't actually close the "<select>" tag...